# How would a creature flee, given an area of difficult terrain?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, terrain

If D is difficult terrain, E is enemy, and C is caster, how would an enemy afflicted by *Fear* flee (or *Command* "Flee"), given the following battlefield:

```
 D
DDD 
 D
 E
 C
```

Would the enemy flee through the difficult terrain, go around it, or flee 'sideways'?

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on the enemy and the type of terrain?

Comment: How intelligent is this enemy? What do you define as difficult?

Comment: Difficult Terrain, as per the rules. Also, intelligent enough to understand the Command spell ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most mindless creatures, e.g. oozes, are immune to the "frightened" condition (and by extension the Fear spell). A creature that's smart enough to be affected by Fear will have the presence of mind to make some basic judgements about its escape route. If there are only two paths away from the source of its fear, and one is clear while the other is littered with obstructing rubble, then even a Giant Constrictor Snake with an Intelligence score of 1 will pick the clear route, *ceteris paribus.*

The language "safest available route" implies this baseline level of presence of mind, even in creatures fleeing in terror. They won't get themselves cornered unnecessarily, or run down hallways that are obviously dead ends: They'll pick whatever route that lets them get further away from the source of their fear, because further is safer.

(I do think it depends, as Joe points out in comments, on the enemy and the type of terrain. But the decisions involved are so simple and instinctive that most creatures are going to react in the same way to most types of terrain. The exceptions will be obvious edge cases, like a creature that flies or is blind.)

In the case presented in the question, the creature will only flee to the other side of the difficult terrain if it's clearly safer than the alternatives. If there's a brick wall that way, the creature will flee to the left or the right. We are led to assume that the creature has identified the area to the "north" as its destination, because otherwise it wouldn't have to make a decision about the difficult terrain.

We know that creatures move at half speed in difficult terrain. If the creature's movement speed is 30 feet (and we're using 5-foot squares), it'll run out of movement for its turn on the northernmost tile of difficult terrain. It'll only take that path if there's no available path that it can take and get further.

We also know that, in the default PHB version of movement on a grid, *moving diagonally is as efficient as moving orthogonally.* Even mindless creatures are "aware" of this, unless your DM has ruled that they move using [taxicab geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). That means that a creature with a movement speed of 30 can spend 10 feet to move northeast to the east side of the difficult terrain, then spend 10 feet to move northwest to the far side of the difficult terrain, and still have 10 feet of movement left with which to get the heck out of Dodge. (Of course, the creature doesn't necessarily have to course-correct to end up on the exact opposite side of the difficult terrain, but the result is the same even if its destination is a square or two to the east or west.)

**Any creature that can detect that there are two clear 20-foot paths around the difficult terrain will opt for one of those** over the 20-foot path to the same square that will cost 35 feet of movement to traverse.

Unless the creature is [Buridan's ass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buridan%27s_ass).

Comment: Yes, taxicab geometry in place =P. It would be weird, but given the difficult terrain, in one sense,  it seems the creature would take the counter-intuitive path of running sideways--it's how they can put more distance between them and you, given their speed. However, that seems awfully calculated.

Answer (score 2):

## This is up to you as a DM

The important part of the Fear spell is as follows:

> While frightened by this spell, a creature must take the Dash action and move away from you by the safest available route on each of its turns, unless there is nowhere to move.

There is nothing in here to suggest that the creature will avoid difficult terrain, or that the ease of egress is taken into consideration when the creature is fleeing.  The creature would likely try to run to the most advantageous spot (in this case, something that breaks line-of-sight) that is also away from the caster.  If that spot happens to be across some difficult terrain, there is nothing in the spell that says the creature wouldn't take this route.

Now, if the difficult terrain is something like spikes or lava (or something else that would cause the creature to take damage) or a cloud of daggers or a poison gas cloud, then the **safest available route** would force the creature to go around.

Finally,  knowledge of the terrain can be a decisive matter here. If the creature is on **familiar terrain**, it's escape path is bound to be chosen on that account. (*i.e.* it knows the best way to get the heck away from that caster!)

Answer (score 1):

### The creature would the shortest, safest, and most efficient route

But you shouldn't be breaking out the calculator to see which route is the most efficient. If you put yourself in the creature's shoes, you can get a feel of how to run. Keep in mind, the creature is frantically running, there isn't much time to think but the creature, regardless of intelligence, knows its options.

In this case, it is to move away, to the left or right and **jump** over the Difficult Terrain, bypassing it entirely and dashing to get away from the source of its fear.

In the case of traps and or secret doors, the creature could still utilize them if it knows of its existence. In one of my games, a fleeing bandit disappeared in a small room through a secret tunnel which the PCs discovered after a Perception Check. In the end, they didn't catch the bandit but they found a secret door that bypassed a ton of traps if they hadn't found it.